# How to change the title of the Tab Dynamically

Tags: android

I have three tabs in my Application. On an event under one Tab, i want to change the title of an another existing Tab. This is the title that we provide while adding the tabs to the TabHost.

Eg: TabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2")).setIndicator("I need to be Changed dynamically").setContent....

In the above example, the title of the tab2 that i provided under setIndicator(), should be changed dynamically.

Is there any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you can find a cleaner method, you can access the `TabWidget` itself.
Contained in the `TabWidget` are relative layouts for each of your tabs which each contain an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. To directly access the textview in the tab at index 0 you can do this:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
```

Then just cast as a `TextView` and you can edit it however you want. The below worked for me:

```
((TextView)mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setText("New");
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than setting the indicator as a `String`, use one where you set the `View` to be used. Then, you can hold onto that `View` (e.g., a `TextView`) and change its contents as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use anymore "TabHost" for ICS, it has been deprecated in version 13. instead you need to you "ActionBar"...

```
Tab mTab = super.getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(0); 
mTab.setText("new Title");
```

Android will refresh the tab right away

Comment: TabHost is not deprecated ! where are you coming up with this ?