# Changing Title from Activities present in tabs in TabLayout in Android

Tags: android

Im trying to change the **title** from the activities inside the Tab. but the title remains same as the Title given for TabActivity. I searched for the solution but not succeeded yet. is there a way to do it? please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the singleton methodology with the TabActivity, then use [This Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291607/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-tab-dynamically) to change the title.

MyTabs.java

```
class MyTabs extends TabActivity {
    private static MyTabs theInstance;

    public static getInstance() {
        return MyTabs.theInstance();
    }

    public MyTabs() {
        MyTabs.theInstance = this;
    }

    ...
}
```

ActivityInTab.java

```
...
TabActivity tabActivity = MyTabs.getInstance();
((TextView)tabActivity.getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setText("New");
...
```

(Obviously this isn't a complete singleton implementation, but it will suffice for what you're doing. Since the activity can't exist without the parent container, it's safe to assume a reference has been set in the constructor when the object was created.)

Comment: hi Gregory i got the point. and also tell me how to change the Application Title pls. (not Tab Title)

Comment: since you already have the reference to the TabActivity, you can just use `tabActivity.setTitle("New Title");`

Comment: Hi Gregory sorry for the late reply . tabActivity.setTitle("New Title"); doesn' t change the application title.

Answer (score 1):

In an Activity used as child of a TabActivity you can use simply

```
getParent().setTitle("your title");
```

the getParent will return the current instance of TabActivuty, than you can change the title