# How to change the name of tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the title of the Tab Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291607/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-tab-dynamically)

I just started android development and i thought i would start to make an app which will contain 3 tabs.

I was wondering how to change the name of tabs?

I tried to change them like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section1).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section2).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section3).setTabListener(this));

    }
```

Is this right because when i change title_section1 nothing changes on the app

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to do it dynamically, you can get a reference to the tab using the tabHost and change it like this:

```
 ((TextView)mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setText("MyTab");
```

This will change the title of tab 0 (first tab) to "MyTab". Similarly, you can access the next tabs with 1,2,3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

please refer [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

Also see below example for it.

```
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();       

      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
              .setIndicator("OPT")
              .setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup1Activity.class)));

      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
              .setIndicator("EDIT")
              .setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup2Activity.class)));

      tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

If any query then let me know.