# How to customize a Material Tab to show its title when its selected only?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabs, material-components-android

I want to make a custom Material Tab, which does only display its text, when the tab itself is selected. Otherwise the icon should be shown alone.

Furthermore the icons should redistribute the free space and only take as much space as needed.

Example video: https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1SkeVD6imJA_MwjipNR-DbNh1xw4au9yy%2F02-rally-tabs.mp4

How can I realise this?

Comment: Your question in unclear. If you want to show the title, why do you want to hide the TextView?

Comment: @Froyo I'm sorry, the 'only' was on the wrong position! When the tab is unselected, theiicon should be shown, when its selected, icon +text shall be shown.

Comment: If you want to hide the text when the tab is not selected, a _hacky_ approach would be to set custom `tabTextAppearance` where you create a style and add `textColor`. In this `textColor` selector, use the tab color when the text is unselected.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try setting the tab title to `""` when unselected?

Comment: You could get access to the texview on the tab by using reflection, although it's not recommended since it's private and it could change upon Android updates... If I remember correctly, the `TexView` is called `title`. So if you get the tab and do `getRoot().findViewById(android.R.id.title)` you should be able to manipulate it. Again, **not** recommended. Check this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2292323/761668

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TabLayout.getTab(position)` to get the tab which was selected and the tabs which are not selected. Once you the `Tab` instance, you can call `Tab.setText("")` and this should remove the title for the tab.

```
val titles = listOf("tab1", "tab2", "tab3")

val tabs = titles.map {
    tabLayout.newTab().also {
        tabLayout.addTab(it)
        it.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    }
}

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        tab?.text = ""
    }

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        val index = tabs.indexOfFirst { it == tab }
        tab?.text = titles[index]

    }

})
```

[image: GIF of the tab behavior]

### Update

You can achieve the effect by using custom view for your Tab.

1 Create a view layout for your Tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="Tab title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2 Use custom view in your `Tab`

```
val tabs = titles.map {
    tabLayout.newTab().also {
        tabLayout.addTab(it)
        val tabView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_item_layout, tabLayout, false)
        tabView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tab_icon).setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        tabView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tab_title).text = title
        it.customView = tabView
    }
}
```

3 Update visibility of the title when the tab is selected.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        tab?.customView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tab_title)?.apply {
            visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        tab?.customView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tab_title)?.apply {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    }

})
```

4 In your declaration of `TabLayout` in XML, you'd need to add `app:tabMode="scrollable"`

[image: Resize-able Tabs]

Comment: Is it possible that the Tabs redistribute the space, so that the full label of the selected tab is visible?

Comment: It should be possible. You'd need to use a custom view for your tab using `tab.setCustomView()` and then you'd have more flexibility.